# Uploading images to an SQLite Database

Tags: python, django, user-interface

What would be the most straight forward way to allow a user to upload images and .pdf documents to an SQLite database through a GUI. OR, perhaps I am looking at webpage solution here - Django has come up in some initial research that I did.

Comment: Don't store the binary stream in the database. Store a filepath in the database where you can retrieve the file. Databases are not good with (large) chunks of data. It will make the database less efficient, and consume more "bandwidth" between the database and the application.

Comment: Thank you, that is good advice about the back end. Yes, it is a storage system that allows a user to organise a collection of images. Any thoughts on how the user could be allowed to upload these images to the system? Do I need to learn JavaScript to make a file upload UI? Or is there a way with Python and HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 0):

### First option: Web application with Django

Developing a minimal Web Application in Django/Flask to allow users to upload images and store them using SQLite3 as DB (check also [storing large binary files in DB vs in Filesystem](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB)) and the default development Web Server provided ([DO NOT USE IT FOR PRODUCTION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver)) is quite straightforward.

If you need a production-ready application, it would be just a bit less straightforward.

If you don't know Django/flask or another backend framework, it would be quite a deal.

And If you also don't have base knowledge about HTTP, HTML forms, computer networks, Web servers, user authentication, sessions, etc... it would be anything except straightforward.

### Second Option: Vanilla upload

If you just want to develop something fast and simple (without user authentication, no security, one upload at a time, no image-user relation, no need of the original image name, etc...) this could be a straightforward way:

1. Develop a Python script that: i. receive the filepath of an image, ii. make a TCP connection, iii. send the data of *one image* over that connection and, iv. close the connection.
2. Develop and run a Python script that create a listening socket that accept connections in a loop and save the data received over each connection as a file.

If you want a GUI for your users, use the [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) package (from the Python Standard Library) in the first script (just a text field for the image path and a submit button to run the script will be enough).

### Other options

Use an open source FTP server for the image uploading, tweak it for your needs and develop a simple FTP client for you users.

Cheers!